# Problem with threads(and redirect) while searching list with queryString 

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, caching, query-string

EDIT: Have updated the code, The remaining problem is that i need to wait for the "The thread '' has exited with code 0" to fire before I can make a new search. If i dont the button events fire, but not the page_Load. Is there a way to handle it?

I am creating a aspx webpage (localhost) to study for a certification. The page contains a grindview that presents data, a search box and a button to summit searches. I use Linq to get the result from the database, querystring to store the search while post-back and the Cache to store the non searched result. The page loads slow the first time and load fast after a refresh (so the caching probably works). The Linq query also gives the expected result and the url on the site is in accord with what the user type in the textbox.

```
Public void Button_Search(object sender, EventArgs e)
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Button Pressed");
        String s = ("~/Matches.aspx");
        if (TextBox1.Text != null && TextBox1.Text != "")
        {
            s = (s + "?Search=" +TextBox1.Text);
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("Redirction adress:" +s);
        Response.Redirect(s, false);
        Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    }
```

then my page_Load function

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("---------------");
            Debug.WriteLine("PageLoad");

            if (Request.QueryString["Search"] != null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("SerchValueFound");
                search = Request.QueryString["Search"];
            }
            if (Cache["MatchesCache"] == null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Cache Loading");
                using (ConnectionToDBDataContext context = new ConnectionToDBDataContext())
                {
                    try
                    {

                        var lista = (from game in context.Games
                                     join home in context.Teams on game.HomeTeamID equals home.TeamID
                                     join away in context.Teams on game.AwayTeamID equals away.TeamID
                                     join arenaName in context.Arenas on game.ArenaID equals arenaName.ArenaID
                                     select new Match
                                     {
                                         MatchID = (int)game.MatchID,
                                         Date = (int)game.Date,
                                         TimeStart = game.TimeStart,
                                         HomeTeam = home.TeamName,
                                         AwayTeam = away.TeamName,
                                         HomeGoals = (int)game.HomeTeamGoals,
                                         AwayGoals = (int)game.AwayTeamGoals,
                                         Arena = arenaName.ArenaName,
                                         Line = "-"
                                     });
                        list = lista.ToList();
                        Cache.Insert("MatchesCache", list, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                    }
                    catch { Debug.WriteLine("Failed to update cache"); }
                }
            }
            list = (List<Match>)Cache["MatchesCache"];
            Debug.WriteLine("List loaded from Cache");


            if (search != null && search != "")
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Search is beeing done");
                List<Match> newList = new List<Match>();
                foreach (Match m in list)
                {
                    if (m.AwayTeam.Contains(search) || m.HomeTeam.Contains(search))
                    {
                        newList.Add(m);
                    }
                }
                list = newList;
            }
            GridView1.DataSource = list;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            search = "";
            Debug.WriteLine("---------------");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting some debug code in there to check whether the list of Match objects are being retrieved from the Cache vs the DB, without using breakpoints?

**---- Update ----**

I've taken your code (except for the database bit) and put it into an ASP.NET 4.0 web application, and it all seems to be working fine...

Here is the aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code-behind for it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                List<Match> list;
                string search = null;

                Debug.WriteLine("---------------");
                Debug.WriteLine("PageLoad");

                if (Request.QueryString["Search"] != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("SerchValueFound");
                    search = Request.QueryString["Search"];
                }

                if (Cache["MatchesCache"] == null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Cache Loading");

                    try
                    {
                        list = new List<Match>
                        {
                            new Match{MatchId = 1, Date = 1, TimeStart = 1, AwayTeam = "the flying fijians", HomeTeam = "wallabies"},
                            new Match{MatchId = 2, Date = 1, TimeStart = 1, AwayTeam = "wallabies", HomeTeam = "all blacks"},
                            new Match{MatchId = 3, Date = 1, TimeStart = 1, AwayTeam = "springboks", HomeTeam = "all blacks"},
                        };

                        Cache.Insert("MatchesCache", list, null, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Failed to update cache");
                    }                    
                }

                list = (List<Match>)Cache["MatchesCache"];
                Debug.WriteLine("List loaded from Cache");

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Search is beeing done");
                    var newList = new List<Match>();

                    foreach (var m in list)
                    {
                        if (m.AwayTeam.Contains(search) || m.HomeTeam.Contains(search))
                        {
                            newList.Add(m);
                        }
                    }
                    list = newList;
                }

                GridView1.DataSource = list;
                GridView1.DataBind();                               

                Debug.WriteLine("---------------");
            }            
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button Pressed");
            var s = ("~/Default.aspx");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox1.Text))
            {
                s = (s + "?Search=" + TextBox1.Text);
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("Redirction adress:" + s);
            Response.Redirect(s, false);            
        }
    }

    public class Match
    {
        public int MatchId { get; set; }
        public int Date { get; set; }
        public int TimeStart { get; set; }
        public string HomeTeam { get; set; }
        public string AwayTeam { get; set; }                                         
    }
}
```

Perhaps it is a problem with your ConnectionToDBDataContext?

Comment: I found some things while using debugcode, if i added 
Debug.WriteLine("Button Pressed"); inside Button_Search the program never wrote it in output. Secondly, every time the search SUCCESSES it writes A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code in output

Comment: The remaining problem is that i need to wait for the "The thread '' has exited with code 0" to fire before I can make a new search. If i dont the button events fire, but not the page_Load.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? I've just created a sample ASP.NET 4.0 and your code seems to work fine - except where are you declaring your 'search' and 'list' variables in the Page_Load handler?

Comment: 4.0, will try to start it at home instead...maybe it will work...Anyway still havent solved it but have made some changes and learned a lot. My current solution makes the button call a javaScript that first change the url and then post a postBack. Before the application first made a page load, then registrer the button click and then made a second page load. Now it just does 1.